# Get entity result with distinct ShipperName

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a query which is returning multiple results set.

```
List<FromAddress> address1 = (from a in stEntities.ShipFromInfoes
                                join b in stEntities.Addresses on a.AddressId equals b.AddressId
                                              where a.ShipperName.StartsWith(namestartwith)                                
                                select new FromAddress()
                                {
                                    ShipperName = a.ShipperName,
                                    TAddressId = a.AddressId,
                                    AddressLine1 = b.AddressLine1,
                                    AddressLine2 = b.AddressLine2,
                                    AddressLine3 = b.AddressLine3,
                                    TelephoneNumber = b.PhoneNumber,
                                    FaxNumber = b.FaxNumber,
                                    MobileNumber = b.MobileNumber
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

In the address1 result I have multiple result with same ShipperName. How do I fetch the result with all fileds with unique ShipperName.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the non-unique addresses...

Comment: I have multiple results with ShipperName "BLUE 1", need to be read as one result instead of multiple.

Comment: So which address should be chosen?

Comment: Any of those. But at the same time I need to keep the result which has the ShipperName as "BLUE 2"

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't say *which* address to take for each unique shipper, but to take the *first* address use:

```
select new FromAddress()
{
...
})
.GroupBy(fa => fa.ShipperName)
.Select(g => g.First())
```